# Airflow UI: hide 'Task Instance Details', section 'Task Attributes', attribute 'env'

Tags: python, user-interface, airflow

I would like to hide the field in Airflow UI: "Task Instance Details" -> Section "Task Attributes" -> Attribute "Env". I have some credentials stored in the envs. I cannot find the solution in Airflow documentation. Do anybody know how to hide the "env" attribute?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in the current version (2.3.0) have the `HIDE_ATTRS_FROM_UI` hardcoded as a class attribute https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.3.0/airflow/www/views.py#L1617 . I do not pass the `env` parameter and the UI shows the None value in the section.